# Canon AE-1 Aperture Lever in camera sticking

Tags: canon, film, aperture

The lens I have confirmed to work on my back other A-1 but for some reason this camera body isn’t allowing the aperture diaphragm to fully close. It’s working from f1.4 to f5.6 but anything more it won’t close any further than f5.6 . Is there a way to fix this? I have a lot of experience fixing small electronics and mechanical bits so if there is I’d be willing to attempt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this happen with more than one lens?

Answer (score 2):

FD mount uses a couple of levers, one to control the aperture setting and one to stop it down when you take the shot or push the DOF preview lever. there can be a couple of issues with these.

If you install the lens with DOF preview engaged on the camera it will put the stop down lever on the wrong side of the one it's supposed to engage with on the lens, and you won't be able to stop down at all.

The camera also remembers the last aperture setting until you advance the film, so if you took your last shot at 5.6 and haven't wound it on, you won't be able to stop down further until you do as the body will be blocking movement of the control lever on the lens, which sounds like what you're experiencing. if it is advanced then It would seem that the control lever on the body is stuck somehow, maybe check the battery in that case, but the camera shouldn't work at all if it's flat but it's cheap to try and at least you end up with a spare battery for your A1. Otherwise it probably requires invasive surgery.

For reference the stop down lever is on the bottom and control lever on the right looking at the body from the front.